# Why does an electron "orbiting" an atomic nucleus have to be described as a standing wave?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electrons, atomic-physics, wave-particle-duality, orbitals

"However, if one describes the electron by a matter wave, a stationary state of the atom in which the electron does not leave the atom must include a standing wave." Why?

Comment: Because if you make that assumption, you get results that match experiments.